# how to filter rss data against javascript array

Tags: javascript

i use the following code to find those items that are not listed in my watch list(items array list). But whenever i run this code the **browser freezes** . if i remove the last **else** part then the program runs fine and prints the items from watch list found in rss feed.

could any one tell me what is wrong my **else part** that it doesn't print items not found in watch list?my goal is to be able to print **only** those items from rss feed that not found in my watch list array.My watch list array has around 700 items in it and rss feed around 1000 items!

```
<script>
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com/rss.php&callback=?', function(data){

var p=0;

 var siteContents = data.contents;
var parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(siteContents,"text/xml");

var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");


for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{

document.myform2.outputtext2.value +=items[i].getElementsByTagName("itemname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"\n";


var myVariable =items[i].getElementsByTagName("itemname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;



items=["mango","apple","orange","banana","book","pen"];



              for (var m=0;m<items.length;m++)
              {

                    if (myVariable == items[m])
                    //if (items[m] == myVariable)
                    { 
                      //do nothing

                        p++;
                       document.myform3.outputtext3.value +=myVariable+"\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         //alert (myVariable);
                     document.myform4.outputtext4.value +=myVariable+"\n";

                    };
             };



 };//end of outer for

});


</script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a http://jsfiddle.net/ to trouble shoot with?

Comment: Why do you assign that array to the same `items` variable which you assigned the xml node collection to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is inverted. Your current script (with the `else` statement) does print an item every time it is not equal to one of the watchlist - every item is printed as many times as your watchlist is long; which makes 700000 lines in that output!

You'd have to move that condition outside the loop. Pseudocode:

```
found = false
foreach item in watchlist
    if item == myvariable // the one you're searching for
        found = true
        break

if found
then putItSomewhere()
else putItSomewhereElse()
```

In an actual script you wouldn't use a loop but simply the [`indexOf` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (items.indexOf(myVariable) == -1) {
    // not found, so output it
    document.myform4.outputtext4.value +=myVariable+"\n";
}
```

Comment: bergi many many thanks that solved the freezing issue. I never knew i could use indexof to search for items in array!